# How to reference an introduction to a text? (Harvard)

Tags: citations, citation-style

I'd like to use the Harvard referencing system to reference a quotation taken from James McFarlane's 1981 introduction to a 2008 reissue of an Oxford World's Classics publication of his *Henrik Ibsen Four Major Plays* collection.

It contains works he translated from original Norwegian.

I have no idea how to reference this.